# Has anyone integrated Selenium into StoryTeller fixtures?

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, acceptance-testing

Has anyone integrated [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) into [StoryTeller](http://storyteller.github.io/) fixtures? How do you do it and what are their roles with respect to the continuous integration?

Comment: StoryTeller is a testing tool for .Net that uses executable scenarios. (http://storyteller.tigris.org). It looks rather defunct - the last update was a preview release made in 2009, and docs are sparse if even present. With that said, @Eatdoku, I've built a solution using Cucumber (another executable scenario tool) and Selenium. Would that answer your question, or are you looking specifically for StoryTeller?

Comment: we are looking into using ST to allow people to build acceptance test from various "sentence" and those tests are actually recorded selenium operations. if that make sense to you. We are also looking into different options, but don't really like the idea of wiki style of creating requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have not used Selenium before, I have used StoryTeller.

These two products will work independently with each other.  There won't be any kind of integration that is built in, but that is not to say that they both can't be leveraged seperately.

StoryTeller can handle your Acceptance testing.
Selenium can handle your UI Automation testing.

Just be careful to not repeat yourself too much when testing.